# no kubelet kubeadm kubectl packages

Tags: kubernetes

I am going through the kebernetes install docs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) and I am at the point where I am suppose to install the `kubelet`, `kubeadm` and `kubectl` RPMs.  I created this yum repo:

```
[root@stg-003 ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
exclude=kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Then I execute this yum command:

```
[root@stg-003 ~]# yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl –disableexcludes=kubernetes
```

Which gives this output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, merge-conf, priorities, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
13024 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package kubelet available.
No package kubeadm available.
No package kubectl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I went here https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/Packages and there are no packages!

So how do I install `kubelet`, `kubeadm` and `kubectl` RPMs?

Comment: They just have the directory listing turned off `curl -I https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/Packages/cf6754a3497c5c05de050f2409eb3b2854467967cf359a8ed9c6e6c32808c7de-kubectl-1.18.0-0.x86_64.rpm` returns 200 OK. Maybe a `yum clean expire-cache` will help?

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks for the suggestion but I still get the same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got bitten by an unfortunate mixture of copy-pasta and the fact that `yum` evidently treats unicode characters as part of package names:

```python
print(repr("[root@stg-003 ~]# yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl –disableexcludes=kubernetes".encode("utf-8")))
>>> b'[root@stg-003 ~]# yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl \xe2\x80\x93disableexcludes=kubernetes'
```

Switching it to the double-dash syntax installs as expected (at least on `centos:7`):

```
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
```

*update:* I went to open a PR for their website but it appears the work is already underway: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/20915

Comment: awesome! that was it. thanks